# Search plugin for wrapping words with text in Gedit v3

Tags: gedit, plugins

I've been searching out for a plugin that could possibly wraps words with specified text.

For example I double click this word to highlight it :

> word

and using a particular shortcut, it becomes as :

> `<b>word</b>` or `myFunction(word);` or ...whatever depending what user defines.

I'm currently using Gedit v3.
It would be really helpful if someone know a place where I can get this type of plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally been using the default plugin "snippet" of Gedit, I didn't know at first One could select and use a Gedit variable ($GEDIT_SELECTED_TEXT) to manage customizable replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Zen Coding](https://github.com/mtrovo/zen-coding-gedit3) plugin.

It offers a bunch of stuff to make writing code easier. It will do the markup wrapping like you're asking.

I'm not sure about the function part, though (I actually don't know anything that will do that, not even the big IDEs like Visual Studio or Eclipse). You might have to use snippets for that one, or accept being able to wrap the highlighted segment in just the parens (which I think Zen does, as well) and manually adding the function name.

Comment: merci a lot, however Zen Coding is appropriate for ones writting html codes.